# EF 6 - many-to-many - Join table without duplicates

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF6 have some confusion on seeding a many to many relationship.

I have the following:

A `User` has **many** saved `ChartQueries` (that they can execute to get a chart).
A `ChartQuery` typically belongs to only one user, but there are several "shared" `ChartQuery`s that every `User` can execute. As a result I set up a **many to many** relationship using a join table `UserChartQuery`. The tables are up in the database just fine at 1-to-many on each side of the join table.

However, I'm not quite understanding how to seed or use this relationship. I don't want to end up with several duplicates of the "shared" `ChartQuery`s (a duplicate for each `User`). Instead, there should only be a single row for each "shared" `ChartQuery` that is a part of each  `User`'s `SavedChartQueries` collection (along with other, non-shared `ChartQuery`s that belong to that `User` only).

It seems like I'm forced to duplicate for each user:

```
  var sharedChartQuery = new ChartQuery { ... }; 
  var nonSharedChartQuery = new ChartQuery { ... };

  var userOneChartQueryOne = new UserChartQuery { User = userOne, ChartQuery = sharedChartQuery  };

  var userTwoChartQueryOne = new UserChartQuery { User = userTwo, ChartQuery = sharedChartQuery };
  var userTwoChartQueryTwo = new UserChartQuery { User = userTwo, ChartQuery = nonSharedChartQuery }; 

  context.UserChartQueries.Add(userOneChartQueryOne);
  context.UserChartQueries.Add(userOneChartQueryTwo);
  context.UserChartQueries.Add(userTwoChartQueryTwo);
```

So first of all is this the right way to seed (through UserChartQueries table directly) or should I seed each `User`'s SavedChartQueries navigation property?

And will this result in duplicate `sharedChartQuery` in the join table for each `User`? If so is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I understand how this works now. The following works as expected:

```
   var userOne = new User {};
   var userTwo = new User {};
   var chartQuery = new ChartQuery { };

        context.Users.Add(userOne);
        context.Users.Add(userTwo);
        context.UserChartQueries.Add(new UserChartQuery { User = userOne, ChartQuery = chartQuery });
        context.UserChartQueries.Add(new UserChartQuery { User = userTwo, ChartQuery = chartQuery });
        context.ChartQueries.Add(chartQuery);
```

The last line adds it to the table where the record actually resides. Checking the join table in SSMS shows that it only holds the foreign keys and nothing else. There are no duplicates.